# cosine similarity and euclidean distance between features of same sample and features of different sample are almost same in tf.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have extracted features from face and left and right iris using MobileNetV2 in keras tensorflow transfer learning. The features are then concatenated. I have tried to find the cosine similarity, euclidean distance and squared euclidean distance between the concatenated features. The distance scores I get for all the metrics do not show much difference between features belonging to the same sample pairs and feature belonging to different samples pairs. I will like have distances between sample features to have smaller distance than distances of different sample pairs. I think I am doing something fundamentally wrong somewhere. I want to be able to plot probability distribution from the scores I get in that the distributions from the different scores should not overlap.

Attached is my code. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from scipy.spatial import distance
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import h5py
import argparse
import random
import math
import tensorflow as tf


modelPath_face = 'HACK-FACE-SMALL-5-02.hdf5'
modelPath_liris = 'HACK-LIRIS-SMALL-5-02.hdf5'
modelPath_riris = 'HACK-RIRIS-SMALL-5-02.hdf5'


def cosine_distance(vests):
    x, y = vests
    x = K.l2_normalize(x, axis=-1)
    y = K.l2_normalize(y, axis=-1)
    return -K.mean(x * y, axis=-1, keepdims=True)


def compute_cosine_distances(a, b):
    # x shape is n_a * dim
    # y shape is n_b * dim
    # results shape is n_a * n_b

    normalize_a = tf.nn.l2_normalize(a, 1)
    normalize_b = tf.nn.l2_normalize(b, 1)
    distance = 1 - tf.matmul(normalize_a, normalize_b, transpose_b=True)
    return distance


def cos_dist_output_shape(shapes):
    shape1, shape2 = shapes
    return (shape1[0], 1)


def eudis(v1, v2):
    dist = [(a - b) ** 2 for a, b in zip(v1, v2)]
    dist = math.sqrt(sum(dist))
    return dist


def Extract(lst):
    return [item[0] for item in lst]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import cv2

    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    ap.add_argument("-df", "--db-face", default=modelPath_face, help="path to face HDF5 file")
    ap.add_argument("-dli", "--db-liris", default=modelPath_liris, help="path to left iris HDF5 file")
    ap.add_argument("-dri", "--db-riris", default=modelPath_riris, help="path to right iris HDF5 file")
    ap.add_argument("-b", "--batch-size", type=int, default=8,
                    help="batch size of images to be passed through network")
    ap.add_argument("-s", "--buffer-size", type=int, default=1000, help="size of feature extraction buffer")

    ap.add_argument('--num-classes', default=53, type=int, metavar='NC',
                    help='number of classes (default: 10000)')
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

    le = LabelEncoder()

    db_face = h5py.File(args["db_face"], "r")
    db_liris = h5py.File(args["db_liris"], "r")
    db_riris = h5py.File(args["db_riris"], "r")

    face_features = db_face["face_features"][:]
    liris_features = db_liris["liris_features"][:]
    riris_features = db_riris["riris_features"][:]

    face_labels = db_face["labels"][:]
    liris_labels = db_liris["labels"][:]
    riris_labels = db_riris["labels"][:]

    n_classes_to_find = le.fit_transform(face_labels)
    n_classes = len(le.classes_)

    args['num_classes'] = n_classes

    face_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(face_labels, num_classes=args['num_classes'])
    liris_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(liris_labels, num_classes=args['num_classes'])
    riris_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(riris_labels, num_classes=args['num_classes'])

    all_features = np.concatenate([face_features, liris_features, riris_features], axis=1)
    all_labels = np.concatenate([face_labels, liris_labels, riris_labels], axis=1)

    all_labels = np.argmax(all_labels, axis=-1)

    stacked_all_ft = np.column_stack((all_features, all_labels))

    columnIndex = stacked_all_ft.shape[1] - 1
    sorted_stacked_all_ft = stacked_all_ft[stacked_all_ft[:, columnIndex].argsort()]

    mylabels = sorted_stacked_all_ft[:, -1]
    myfeatures = sorted_stacked_all_ft[:, :-1]

    unique_labels = np.unique(mylabels)
    myfeatures_shape = myfeatures.shape

    # pca = PCA(0.9)
    #
    # pca.fit(myfeatures)
    #
    # PCA(copy=True, iterated_power='auto', n_components=0.9, random_state=None,
    #     svd_solver='auto', tol=0.0, whiten=False)
    #
    # print(pca.n_components_)
    #
    # myfeatures_pca = pca.transform(myfeatures)

    df_pos_pair = pd.DataFrame()
    df_neg_pair = pd.DataFrame()
    positive_counter = 0
    general_counter = 0
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
    print("COMPARISON OF ALL FILES: Started")

    myfeatures_pca = myfeatures
    for i in range(myfeatures_pca.shape[0]):
        for j in range(myfeatures_pca.shape[0]):
            if j > i:
                general_counter += 1
                pair_pos = mylabels[j] == mylabels[i]
                if pair_pos:
                    positive_counter += 1
                    try:
                        f1 = myfeatures_pca[i]
                        f2 = myfeatures_pca[j]

                        # score = tf.keras.losses.cosine_similarity(f1, f2, axis=-1)
                        # score = score.numpy()

                        # aa = f1.reshape(1, -1)
                        # ba = f2.reshape(1, -1)
                        # score = cosine_similarity(aa, ba)
                        # score = score[0][0]

                        # score = eudis(f1, f2)

                        score = distance.sqeuclidean(f1, f2)

                        # if i in data1.index and j in data1.columns:
                        df_pos_pair = df_pos_pair.append({'score': score}, ignore_index=True)
                        general_counter += 1
                        if general_counter % 25 == 0:
                            end_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
                            print("COMPLETED OF ALL FILES: {}, TOTAL TIME: {}".format(general_counter,
                                                                                      (end_time - start_time)))

                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)

                else:
                    for k2 in range(positive_counter):
                        r = random.randint(j + 1, myfeatures_pca.shape[0] - 2)
                        if mylabels[r] != mylabels[i]:
                            try:
                                f3 = myfeatures_pca[i]
                                f4 = myfeatures_pca[r]

                                # scoren = tf.keras.losses.cosine_similarity(f3, f4, axis=-1)
                                # scoren = score.numpy()

                                scoren = distance.sqeuclidean(f3, f4)

                                # aa2 = f3.reshape(1, -1)
                                # ba2 = f4.reshape(1, -1)
                                # scoren = cosine_similarity(aa2, ba2)
                                # scoren = scoren[0][0]

                                # scoren = eudis(f3, f4)

                                df_neg_pair = df_neg_pair.append({'score': scoren}, ignore_index=True)
                                general_counter += 1
                                end_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
                                print("COMPLETED OF ALL FILES: {}, TOTAL TIME: {}".format(general_counter,
                                                                                          (end_time - start_time)))
                            except Exception as e:
                                print(e)

                        positive_counter = 0
                        break
    end_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
    print("COMPARISON OF ALL FILES: Ended in {} ".format((end_time - start_time)))
    df_neg_pair.to_csv("sqed_face_iris_neg_scores_pca_feb_01.csv", index=False)

    df_pos_pair.to_csv("sqed_face_iris_pos_scores_pca_feb_01.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: I think this is too much code to be thrown at us without explanation. You more likely get an answer if you post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The hdf5 files represent the features extracted from face, left and right iris which are saved as hdf5 files. Following that, I have defined the metrics for the loss function. In the main section, I import the features and labels from the three hdf5 files i.e face features, face labels, left iris features, left iris labels, right iris features, right iris labels. I concatenate the features and name it myfeatures. I also concatenate the labels and call it mylabels. I then pair up the features (myfeatures) against each other in the loop